# Escaping backslashes in string.replace

Tags: asp.net, string, escaping

I have an image control with the following string

```
http://test.site.com\Content\Images\ProductImages\73\700-4aad-be94-e0b79982951f_0_Chrysanthemum__Product_Search.jpg
```

I want to replace `string cleartext=imagePath.Replace("\","/");` but the backslash causes a problem -- how can I replace the backslash?

Answer (score 3):

The backslash is a special character in strings that starts an escape sequence. You need to "escape" the \, so you should use imagePath.replace("\\","/")

Comment: Alternative: imagePath.Replace(@"\", "/");

Answer (score 3):

You can escape the string characters individually with "\" or you can change any string into a String literal by prefixing it with an `@`.

Documentation for this is available at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx.

Another good resource for understanding how strings work in C# is: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx.